# Missing artifact net.sf.ha-jdbc:ha-jdbc:jar:3.0.0-rc-1

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jdbc, artifact

We are trying to switch databases for our Spring boot application, in case one fails. We are using hibernate as our `ORM`. So we found this link [Primary/Secondary failover DataSource in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800582/primary-secondary-failover-datasource-in-spring-boot), which redirected to [Using HA-JDBC with Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/using-ha-jdbc-with-spring-boot).

But when we tried to add the dependency for `HA-JDBC`, we were getting error like `Missing artifact net.sf.ha-jdbc:ha-jdbc:jar:3.0.0-rc-1`, this was the location [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ha-jdbc/ha-jdbc). We tried with all the versions but the error is same. We tried cleaning the project and updating the project but the error is still there.

This is the dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ha-jdbc/ha-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ha-jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ha-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-rc-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This artifact is not on Maven Central, but - according to your link - available from the JBoss 3rd-party repository. Did you add that repository to your configuration? Otherwise Maven doesn't know where to find it.

Comment: Adding repository to the configuration means add to the `.m2` folder in the respective user's folder right? We are using Windows OS.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also define it in the pom.xml, eg see [Add Maven repositories for a project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429142/add-maven-repositories-for-a-project-in-eclipse)